# Can't deploy aspnet with C# & F# to azure - All build submissions in a build must use project instances originating from the same project collection

Tags: azure, f#, .net-core

I'm starting a new web application, I wanted to use aspnetcore and the latest libraries and tools but I also wanted to use a functional, immutable language for the backend (the domain is one of those where OOP is specially painful to use) so we decided to go with F#

The thing is: aspnetcore for F# tooling is not yet on par with C# tooling (visual studio support, debugging, etc), so we decided to build the frontend in C# and the backend in F#. I was able to get it to build and run locally but when I try pushing it to azure I get an error

> All build submissions in a build must use project instances originating from the same project collection

This is my environment:

```
OS: Windows
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 v15.2
```

Steps:

1. Open Visual Studio 2017
2. Create new project (choose ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework))
3. Choose "Empty template"
4. Add new project to solution (choose F# Library)
5. Add reference from WebProject to Library
6. Compile & Run -> Everything OK
7. Publish webproject to azure and get this error:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: WebApplication23, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>       1>WebApplication23 -> C:*****\WebApplication23\WebApplication23\bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\WebApplication23.exe
>       2>------ Publish started: Project: WebApplication23, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>       All build submissions in a build must use project instances originating from the same project collection.
>       2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

If instead of an F# project I create a classic desktop C# library, it deploys successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently dealing with very similar issues. Same type of solution, C# on the front end and F# on the back. There are some serious bugs with the publish system in VS 2017.  I was down nearly 3 days before I came across this which allows me to publish only via the command line.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/36498/publish-fails-with-all-build-submissions-in-a-buil.html

Comment: Yes. That's what I ended up doing. I forgot about this question, I'm accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings under "summary" in the publish tab, and you'll probably notice that the build configuration differs from the other Projects (this seem to override what you set in other places).

/Dagfinn

Comment: It says "Release"